# What was adi shankaracharya's views on Buddhism?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya

How did adi shankara view Buddhists. Did he consider them to be on right path or did he consider them to be on wrong path.

Did he believe that, if so one follows buddhist philosophy (alone) will attain Moksha.

Comment: He has written a Brahma Sutra Commentary where the Buddhists are referred to as Shunyavadis and Vijnanavadis. I’m sure there would most likely be an existing question for this.

Comment: Interestingly, he adopts slightly different positions towards Buddhism. In Mandukya and Gaudapada karika bhAshya, he acknowledges that one particular school of Buddhism is at least partly correct. However, in Brahmasutra bhashya, he makes an unqualified rejection of Buddhism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regards how did Shankaracharya view Buddhists , its already answered here [1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/42697/19211) and
[2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/40551/19211) .
As regards to his view if Buddhists get Moksha, he opinions that his path is better than Buddhism but in end says if Buddhists accept Vedas, they can be included among Vedantic Schools which perhaps means they are eligible for same Moksha as all Advaitans in his opinion.

> But if the Bauddhas accept the authority of the Vedas, then they would
> be included within the Vedantic school and no longer remain outside
> it, but as a matter of fact they do not accept the Vedas. (Bramha
> Sutra Bhasya of Shankaracharya 2.2.29)

He also worshipped Buddha in Hari Hara Stotra Verse 10 :

> I worship the spiritual radiance manifested as Buddha, who was
> all-knowing, who was the conqueror of Mara, who was full of mercy, who
> was of the nature of Bodha (spiritual consciousness), and who was the
> adored of those who were opponents of Yagnyas.

Comment: Please provide reference links for first quotation.

Comment: "means they are eligible for same Moksha" please provide reference for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: When he is saying that Buddhists would be included within Vedantic school, What does it mean @DarkKnight ?

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru so they are not eligible for moksha if they reject vedas

Comment: He doesn't say it XD ! Problem is you want one sect to accept all other sects ! If they do so their own sect will collapse ! Do Dwaithans agree Advaithans will get Moksha ! NO! @DarkKnight

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru so what does he say.

Comment: He is saying they can be subpart of his school if they accept vedas @DarkKnight